# What is better to call the menu title?

Tags: navigation, menu

First take a look at the screenshot below.

[image]

This page consists of a side menu on the left, and a list of room types on the right.

The problem I have found with this, is that some users don't want to click the menu item "Room Type" when they need to list a room for the first time.

This may be because they don't see the words List Room Type when they are on any other page.

What should I call the menu item?

Comment: Are you creating the entire room (type, rate, person allowed) when you click "List room"? If so I think the issue is you shouldn't be focusing on just the type but the whole "Room" or "Room Listing".

Comment: @DasBeasto yes list room button leads to long form. thanks for better word.

Comment: Have you asked why they don’t want to click on it?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, your page is there to:

- View currently listed rooms (including setting type/rate/persons allowed)
- List new rooms

Unless I'm misunderstanding, "Room Type" seems to be one of a few features of this page. Why not call it something like "Listed Rooms" - which is more descriptive of the content on the page.